# How to install lightblue (bluetooth) module on Snow Leopard?

Tags: python, gcc, bluetooth, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to install the bluetooth module from [lightblue](http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/).

My system: Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8, Python 2.7, gcc 4.2 & 4.0, xcode v.3.2.3 .
I checked , i also got python 2.3/2.5/2.6 folders directly under /Library/Python/ in my system (This is different from 2.7 which is located in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/)

When I install lightblue with `python setup.py install`, I get the following error:

```
GCC 4.2 is not compatible with the Mac OS X 10.4 SDK (file BBBluetoothOBEXClient.m)
** BUILD FAILED **
```

So I thought it was about the gcc version. So I did: 'export CC=gcc-4.0'  or 'export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.0' (I got 2 versions of gcc on my Mac; 4.2 and 4.0). Then I checked with `gcc -v`, it's already switched from 4.2 to 4.0. But when I rerun `python setup.py install`, it is still showing 4.2:

```
GCC 4.2 is not compatible with the Mac OS X 10.4 SDK (file BBBluetoothOBEXClient.m)
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Why is it still showing gcc 4.2?

Does anyone have any solution? I tried using pip but got the same result.

Comment: @Mark : xcode is v.3.2.3 ( i've just edited my post above) , installed from apple installation dvd without problem.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found the solution, I grabbed this from : [lightblue](http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/)

**For Mac OS 10.6 users:**

1. Open src/mac/_lightblue.py and change **signature="v@:@iB"** to **signature="v@:@iZ"** (line 468)
2. Download and unzip **LightAquaBlue-python-MacOS10.6.zip**, which contains a LightAquaBlue directory. Move this directory into your python site-packages library, e.g. /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
3. Download and unzip **LightAquaBlue-framework-MacOS10.6.zip**, which contains a (completely different) LightAquaBlue directory. Move this directory into src/mac to replace the existing src/mac/LightAquaBlue directory. This should fix the architecture/build problems that existed with the old LightAquaBlue xcode project.
4. Run **python setup.py install** as per normal to install.

Now when running `python setup.py install` ,I got this : `** BUILD SUCCEEDED **` 
Using pip will fail, except we alter some of installation source folders as above.
I got 'build succeeded', but haven't tested the module yet, as I need to finish other installation steps. I'm installing nxt-python ( python interface to control/program my lego mindstorm NXT -> [nxt-python](http://code.google.com/p/nxt-python/wiki/Installation)).