# some error for pybluez. I can't import bluetooth

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, pybluez

I have problem about pybluez

This is my code

```
import bluetooth
```

then it's showing error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bluetooth/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .osx import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bluetooth/osx.py", line 1, in <module>
    import lightblue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightblue/__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
    from ._lightblue import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightblue/_lightblue.py", line 29, in <module>
    from . import _LightAquaBlue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightblue/_LightAquaBlue.py", line 33, in <module>
    _FRAMEWORK_PATH)
ImportError: Cannot load LightAquaBlue framework, not found at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightblue/LightAquaBlue.framework
```

what I have to do for fix this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284694/how-to-install-lightblue-bluetooth-module-on-snow-leopard

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem. Here is my solution.

1. Make sure you have installed [lightblue](https://github.com/0-1-0/lightblue-0.4).
2. create a link of LightAquaBlue.framework: 
   `ln -s /Library/Frameworks/LightAquaBlue.framework /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightblue/LightAquaBlue.framework`